# running different command on different machine with same alias name in .bashrc

Tags: bash, alias

Depending on machine I have to access file with same name but from different directory. So currently I have one alias per machine for the file being accessed.

But is it possible to check the machine on which current session is being opened and then just source aliases corresponding to that machine. Something like below in bashrc

```
If(machine1) 
   alias a1='command1'
else if (machine2)
   alias a1='command2'
else
   alias a1='command3'
```

Comment: Yes, how are you accessing the machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hostname
e.g.

```
case $(hostname) in
    host1)  alias a1='echo host1';;
    host2)  alias a1='echo host2';;
    host3)  alias a1='echo host3';;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are under Linux, you could discriminate among your machines based on the `MAC` address of your Ethernet card. The `MAC` address is generally unique, unless you messed with it somehow.

Get the `MAC` address like this:

```
MACHINEID=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
```

Then you can do something like:

```
if [ $MACHINEID = "mac_address_of_machine_1_here" ];
then
#whatever
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have your .bashrc source another init file that can have a unique name

```
# .bashrc
. .bash_$(hostname)
```

```
# .bash_host1
alias a1=command1
```

```
# .bash_host2
alias a1=command2
```

etc